# How to view movie taken on Android Lenovo Tab device via Xender on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 4s, and have installed xender for iOS. When I record a movie in mkv and flv video from android via xender, the transfer to the iPhone completes but the movie cannot be viewed.

Comment: Maybe the format of the video you are trying to play on iPhone is not supported. And also could you tell us what format are you trying to play on xender?

Answer (score 1):

I'm from Xender representative, I am sorry for inconvenience.
I personally just tried to send MP4 Video from Sony Xperia Z2 to iPhone 5 via Xender and yes the video played perfectly on Xender.

Please don't hesitate to send us some message if you have more questions and feedback to anmobi@xender.cn we will try our best to help you for all your issues.